# No network on Ubuntu Server 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I lazily swapped a HDD with Ubuntu out of another old PC into a new one and although everything else works fine the network doesn't seem to come on until I run `sudo dhclient`.

I have tried all kinds of settings within `/etc/network/interfaces` and nothing seems to work for me there. The network adapter shows as `enp4s0` when i run `ifconfig -a` so have set like below along with a host of other examples I have found for static IP etc:

> **/etc/network/interfaces**

```
# /etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for ifup(8), ifdown(8)
# Generated by debian-installer.

# The loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp4s0
allow-hotplug enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet dhcp
```

This is a headless server so it is difficult to show results of ifconfig prior to having network however no ip addresses show.

Once I run `dhclient` with network ifconfig -a outputs:

```
enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.60  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::a60:6eff:fee5:e58b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 08:60:6e:e5:e5:8b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 5486  bytes 573445 (573.4 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 155  bytes 18460 (18.4 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 4934  bytes 393603 (393.6 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 4934  bytes 393603 (393.6 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Why are you using DHCP to configure the IP address of a server? I suggest you try capturing the network traffic from the DHCP server side. It's quite likely you'll find something amiss whit the DHCP communication while your server is booting.

Comment: @kasperd Its just a dev box I use and was on static previously but i've tried all options to just get it going really as felt it was something amiss with having a new network adapter rather than DHCP and less I could do wrong when setting DHCP. Not sure how to check the DHCP server its just a home router.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 is past end of life. Update to a supported Ubuntu or Ubuntu LTS release. And remember that this is a site for professional IT and we do not handle home servers or networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 17.10 uses [NetPlan](https://netplan.io/) already, so probably you should take a look into `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` and change your interface name there accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly it: enp1s0 was set rather than enp4s0.